# Mapping array values to object based on key

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, object

I have a Javascript array with a number of arrays inside , like this:

```
var data = [
  ['value1','value2','value3'],
  ['value1','value2','value3'],
  ['value1','value2','value3'],
  ['value1','value2','value3']
];
```

I also have another array with a key for these values:

```
var key = ['width', 'height', 'depth'];
```

What's the best ways to loop through the `data` array and map the values to their respective keys, returning an object?

Example:

```
function(data, key) {
  /*
  var newObject = {
    {width: 'value1', height: 'value2', 'depth': 'value3'},
    {width: 'value1', height: 'value2', 'depth': 'value3'},
    {width: 'value1', height: 'value2', 'depth': 'value3'},
    {width: 'value1', height: 'value2', 'depth': 'value3'}
  }
  return newObject;
  */
}
```

**edit:

I mistakenly initially posed the question as trying to map arrays inside of *objects*, it should have been arrays inside of *arrays*. Question now should reflect my problem correctly.

Comment: That doesn't look like valid syntax. Once you fix it, look into [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

Comment: *"I have a Javascript object with a number of arrays inside"* That's not valid JS. Do you have an array of arrays instead? There are multiple ways to iterate over collections: `for`, `for/in`, `Array#.map`, `Array#forEach`. There is not a "best" way per se, use whatever is most comprehensible to you. Have you tried anything at all?

Comment: @user4703663: You should let the OP clarify their question.

Comment: Sorry, an array of array, editing post now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var data = [
  ['value1','value2','value3'],
  ['value1','value2','value3'],
  ['value1','value2','value3'],
  ['value1','value2','value3']
];

var keys = ['width', 'height', 'depth'];

var obj  = [];
for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  for(var j = 0; j < keys.length; j++) {
    if(obj[i] == undefined) {
      obj[i] = []
      obj[i][keys[j]] = data[i][j];
    } else {
      obj[i][keys[j]] = data[i][j];
    }
  }
}

console.log(obj);
```

Comment: This returns an array, I'd like to return an object with objects inside.

Comment: the keys of the hash should be uniq. Example above has invalid syntax, you can try to uncomment it, and as far as I understood it has to be an array of hashes.